# Passing class instance through a variable

Tags: php, oop

I was creating a plugin system where plugins are stored in php classes.Each plugin uses the class instance of the main package to execute its functions.

```
<?php
class main {
  //Class methods
  ...

  function execute(){
    ...
  }

  function load_plugin($name) {
    ...
    include 'plugins/' . $name . '.php';
    $this-> {$name}=new $name ($this);
    return true;
  }
```

And in 'plugins/example.php:'

```
<?php 
class example {
  function __construct($main){
    $this->main=$main;
  }

  function delete(){
    $this->main->execute();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't  manage to pass the class instance into the plugin.I tried using define but could not manage.
How can I pass the current class instance into the plugin?

Comment: I think you need to implement __get and __set methods so your   main->load_plugin($name)   and inside it:  $this->{$name} = new ....  would even work.

Also maybe you will use `extends` not injecting the classes into constructors.

Answer (score 0):

to use method of `main` class you have to extend you `example` class

```
class example extends main{
//you cade
}
```

Comment: That will mean I use a **new class instance** for each plugin.What I really want is to use one class instance for all plugins such as :
`    $main->plugin1->method();
    $main->plugin2->method2();
    $main->plugin3->method3();
`